# "Peer Review" badge description is HTML-encoded in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, badges, ios-app

The apostrophe in the description of the new documentation badge "Peer Review" is HTML-encoded:

[image: I'll add a freehand circle soon!]

This doesn't happen on the website, so it's probably a bug in the iOS app.

(I don't know if this happens to other badges too.  If I or someone else finds out that it does, I'll update the question to be more generic.)

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 5c (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.1.

The API for the feed (and other app specific stuff) isn't fully documented like the public API and there are places where I incorrectly assume I'm getting an unescaped string.